# How can I get an ID token with an access token?

Tags: aws-lambda, openid-connect, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-cognito, google-openid

Currently I have a lambda function that is receiving a Google access token. However, in order to receive a cognito ID, AWS Cognito only accepts an ID token, rather than an access token.

Is there anyway I can exchange a Google access token for an ID token? If not, how can I get a cognito identity ID from my access token?

I would try to provide the lambda function with an ID token; however, Alexa is the one calling lambda with the access token, and I can't seem to find a way to configure Alexa to call the lambda function with an ID token instead.

For context, I am trying to get info associated with a cognito ID using Amazon Alexa.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't get an id token from an access token. They provide different functionality.

Answer (score 0):

id token is returned together with access token in the token response. you need to modify your lambda function or create a new one to spit it out from the google token response

e.g. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#exchangecode